# Frequently getting 429 error on using the PnP powershell script, this script is calling OneDrive content. How can we fix this issue?

Tags: pnp-powershell, onedrive-for-business

We have configured 5-6 window schedulers to call powerShell scripts to fetch the OneDrive content. but PnP powershell script throwing below errors on the VM event viewer:

1. Faulting application name: dwm.exe, version: 10.0.19041.1, time
   stamp: 0x9a82ecd.
2. The storage optimizer couldn't complete slab
   consolidation on Temporary Storage.
3. Faulting application name:
   PowerShell.EXE, version: 10.0.19041.1, time stamp: 0xc37343ae
   Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll,

Comment: HTTP 429 means you're being throttled. Can you instead state what you're attempting to do so we can offer advice on that?

Comment: yes its throttling issue , we are migrating content from OneDrive to SharePoint Online..can we identify throttling by PS script and fix it.?

Comment: The best you can do is not migrate during business hours. I would also use a 3rd party migration tool, like Sharegate. It will handle the throttling for you, but you won't avoid throttling as you're migrating between online services.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/282238/system-net-webexception-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-429/

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving an HTTP 429 response, then it is likely that you are being throttled. Microsoft have provided documentation on how to avoid being throttled:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online

An important way of dealing with throttling is using the Retry-After HTTP header. This is clarified by Microsoft in their advice:

> If you do run into throttling, we require leveraging the Retry-After HTTP header to ensure minimum delay until the throttle is removed.

> The Retry-After HTTP header is the fastest way to handle being
> throttled because SharePoint Online dynamically determines the right
> time to try again. In other words, aggressive retries work against you
> because even though the calls fail, they still accrue against your
> usage limits. Following the Retry-After HTTP header will ensure the
> shortest delay.